# Reset jQuery animation after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an animation setup where after you click "open" button an animation is triggered. What I want to do is have it so that when you click "close" the animation is reset so that I can go and click "open" again to trigger animation again.

```js
$('#open').click(function() {
  //front page
  $('#first').css({
    transformOrigin: '0px 0px',
    backfaceVisibility: 'hidden'
  }).transition({
    transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'
  }, '2000');
  //back of front page
  $('#third').css({
    transformOrigin: '0px 0px',
  }).transition({
    transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'
  }, '2000', function() {
    //group hide
    $('#group').hide();
    $('#fourth').show(0, function() {
      $(this).css({
        transformOrigin: '0px 0px',
        backfaceVisibility: 'hidden'
      }).transition({
        transform: 'rotateX(180deg)'
      }, '2000');
    });
    $('#sixth').show(0, function() {
      $(this).css({
        transformOrigin: '0px 0px',
      }).transition({
        transform: 'rotateX(180deg)'
      }, '2000');
    });
    $('#fifth').show();
  });
});

$('#close').click(function() {
//not sure what to put to reset 
});

(function(t, e) {
  if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(["jquery"], e)
  } else if (typeof exports === "object") {
    module.exports = e(require("jquery"))
  } else {
    e(t.jQuery)
  }
})(this, function(t) {
  t.transit = {
    version: "0.9.12",
    propertyMap: {
      marginLeft: "margin",
      marginRight: "margin",
      marginBottom: "margin",
      marginTop: "margin",
      paddingLeft: "padding",
      paddingRight: "padding",
      paddingBottom: "padding",
      paddingTop: "padding"
    },
    enabled: true,
    useTransitionEnd: false
  };
  var e = document.createElement("div");
  var n = {};

  function i(t) {
    if (t in e.style) return t;
    var n = ["Moz", "Webkit", "O", "ms"];
    var i = t.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + t.substr(1);
    for (var r = 0; r < n.length; ++r) {
      var s = n[r] + i;
      if (s in e.style) {
        return s
      }
    }
  }

  function r() {
    e.style[n.transform] = "";
    e.style[n.transform] = "rotateY(90deg)";
    return e.style[n.transform] !== ""
  }
  var s = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome") > -1;
  n.transition = i("transition");
  n.transitionDelay = i("transitionDelay");
  n.transform = i("transform");
  n.transformOrigin = i("transformOrigin");
  n.filter = i("Filter");
  n.transform3d = r();
  var a = {
    transition: "transitionend",
    MozTransition: "transitionend",
    OTransition: "oTransitionEnd",
    WebkitTransition: "webkitTransitionEnd",
    msTransition: "MSTransitionEnd"
  };
  var o = n.transitionEnd = a[n.transition] || null;
  for (var u in n) {
    if (n.hasOwnProperty(u) && typeof t.support[u] === "undefined") {
      t.support[u] = n[u]
    }
  }
  e = null;
  t.cssEase = {
    _default: "ease",
    "in": "ease-in",
    out: "ease-out",
    "in-out": "ease-in-out",
    snap: "cubic-bezier(0,1,.5,1)",
    easeInCubic: "cubic-bezier(.550,.055,.675,.190)",
    easeOutCubic: "cubic-bezier(.215,.61,.355,1)",
    easeInOutCubic: "cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1)",
    easeInCirc: "cubic-bezier(.6,.04,.98,.335)",
    easeOutCirc: "cubic-bezier(.075,.82,.165,1)",
    easeInOutCirc: "cubic-bezier(.785,.135,.15,.86)",
    easeInExpo: "cubic-bezier(.95,.05,.795,.035)",
    easeOutExpo: "cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1)",
    easeInOutExpo: "cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1)",
    easeInQuad: "cubic-bezier(.55,.085,.68,.53)",
    easeOutQuad: "cubic-bezier(.25,.46,.45,.94)",
    easeInOutQuad: "cubic-bezier(.455,.03,.515,.955)",
    easeInQuart: "cubic-bezier(.895,.03,.685,.22)",
    easeOutQuart: "cubic-bezier(.165,.84,.44,1)",
    easeInOutQuart: "cubic-bezier(.77,0,.175,1)",
    easeInQuint: "cubic-bezier(.755,.05,.855,.06)",
    easeOutQuint: "cubic-bezier(.23,1,.32,1)",
    easeInOutQuint: "cubic-bezier(.86,0,.07,1)",
    easeInSine: "cubic-bezier(.47,0,.745,.715)",
    easeOutSine: "cubic-bezier(.39,.575,.565,1)",
    easeInOutSine: "cubic-bezier(.445,.05,.55,.95)",
    easeInBack: "cubic-bezier(.6,-.28,.735,.045)",
    easeOutBack: "cubic-bezier(.175, .885,.32,1.275)",
    easeInOutBack: "cubic-bezier(.68,-.55,.265,1.55)"
  };
  t.cssHooks["transit:transform"] = {
    get: function(e) {
      return t(e).data("transform") || new f
    },
    set: function(e, i) {
      var r = i;
      if (!(r instanceof f)) {
        r = new f(r)
      }
      if (n.transform === "WebkitTransform" && !s) {
        e.style[n.transform] = r.toString(true)
      } else {
        e.style[n.transform] = r.toString()
      }
      t(e).data("transform", r)
    }
  };
  t.cssHooks.transform = {
    set: t.cssHooks["transit:transform"].set
  };
  t.cssHooks.filter = {
    get: function(t) {
      return t.style[n.filter]
    },
    set: function(t, e) {
      t.style[n.filter] = e
    }
  };
  if (t.fn.jquery < "1.8") {
    t.cssHooks.transformOrigin = {
      get: function(t) {
        return t.style[n.transformOrigin]
      },
      set: function(t, e) {
        t.style[n.transformOrigin] = e
      }
    };
    t.cssHooks.transition = {
      get: function(t) {
        return t.style[n.transition]
      },
      set: function(t, e) {
        t.style[n.transition] = e
      }
    }
  }
  p("scale");
  p("scaleX");
  p("scaleY");
  p("translate");
  p("rotate");
  p("rotateX");
  p("rotateY");
  p("rotate3d");
  p("perspective");
  p("skewX");
  p("skewY");
  p("x", true);
  p("y", true);

  function f(t) {
    if (typeof t === "string") {
      this.parse(t)
    }
    return this
  }
  f.prototype = {
    setFromString: function(t, e) {
      var n = typeof e === "string" ? e.split(",") : e.constructor === Array ? e : [e];
      n.unshift(t);
      f.prototype.set.apply(this, n)
    },
    set: function(t) {
      var e = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
      if (this.setter[t]) {
        this.setter[t].apply(this, e)
      } else {
        this[t] = e.join(",")
      }
    },
    get: function(t) {
      if (this.getter[t]) {
        return this.getter[t].apply(this)
      } else {
        return this[t] || 0
      }
    },
    setter: {
      rotate: function(t) {
        this.rotate = b(t, "deg")
      },
      rotateX: function(t) {
        this.rotateX = b(t, "deg")
      },
      rotateY: function(t) {
        this.rotateY = b(t, "deg")
      },
      scale: function(t, e) {
        if (e === undefined) {
          e = t
        }
        this.scale = t + "," + e
      },
      skewX: function(t) {
        this.skewX = b(t, "deg")
      },
      skewY: function(t) {
        this.skewY = b(t, "deg")
      },
      perspective: function(t) {
        this.perspective = b(t, "px")
      },
      x: function(t) {
        this.set("translate", t, null)
      },
      y: function(t) {
        this.set("translate", null, t)
      },
      translate: function(t, e) {
        if (this._translateX === undefined) {
          this._translateX = 0
        }
        if (this._translateY === undefined) {
          this._translateY = 0
        }
        if (t !== null && t !== undefined) {
          this._translateX = b(t, "px")
        }
        if (e !== null && e !== undefined) {
          this._translateY = b(e, "px")
        }
        this.translate = this._translateX + "," + this._translateY
      }
    },
    getter: {
      x: function() {
        return this._translateX || 0
      },
      y: function() {
        return this._translateY || 0
      },
      scale: function() {
        var t = (this.scale || "1,1").split(",");
        if (t[0]) {
          t[0] = parseFloat(t[0])
        }
        if (t[1]) {
          t[1] = parseFloat(t[1])
        }
        return t[0] === t[1] ? t[0] : t
      },
      rotate3d: function() {
        var t = (this.rotate3d || "0,0,0,0deg").split(",");
        for (var e = 0; e <= 3; ++e) {
          if (t[e]) {
            t[e] = parseFloat(t[e])
          }
        }
        if (t[3]) {
          t[3] = b(t[3], "deg")
        }
        return t
      }
    },
    parse: function(t) {
      var e = this;
      t.replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\((.*?)\)/g, function(t, n, i) {
        e.setFromString(n, i)
      })
    },
    toString: function(t) {
      var e = [];
      for (var i in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          if (!n.transform3d && (i === "rotateX" || i === "rotateY" || i === "perspective" || i === "transformOrigin")) {
            continue
          }
          if (i[0] !== "_") {
            if (t && i === "scale") {
              e.push(i + "3d(" + this[i] + ",1)")
            } else if (t && i === "translate") {
              e.push(i + "3d(" + this[i] + ",0)")
            } else {
              e.push(i + "(" + this[i] + ")")
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return e.join(" ")
    }
  };

  function c(t, e, n) {
    if (e === true) {
      t.queue(n)
    } else if (e) {
      t.queue(e, n)
    } else {
      t.each(function() {
        n.call(this)
      })
    }
  }

  function l(e) {
    var i = [];
    t.each(e, function(e) {
      e = t.camelCase(e);
      e = t.transit.propertyMap[e] || t.cssProps[e] || e;
      e = h(e);
      if (n[e]) e = h(n[e]);
      if (t.inArray(e, i) === -1) {
        i.push(e)
      }
    });
    return i
  }

  function d(e, n, i, r) {
    var s = l(e);
    if (t.cssEase[i]) {
      i = t.cssEase[i]
    }
    var a = "" + y(n) + " " + i;
    if (parseInt(r, 10) > 0) {
      a += " " + y(r)
    }
    var o = [];
    t.each(s, function(t, e) {
      o.push(e + " " + a)
    });
    return o.join(", ")
  }
  t.fn.transition = t.fn.transit = function(e, i, r, s) {
    var a = this;
    var u = 0;
    var f = true;
    var l = t.extend(true, {}, e);
    if (typeof i === "function") {
      s = i;
      i = undefined
    }
    if (typeof i === "object") {
      r = i.easing;
      u = i.delay || 0;
      f = typeof i.queue === "undefined" ? true : i.queue;
      s = i.complete;
      i = i.duration
    }
    if (typeof r === "function") {
      s = r;
      r = undefined
    }
    if (typeof l.easing !== "undefined") {
      r = l.easing;
      delete l.easing
    }
    if (typeof l.duration !== "undefined") {
      i = l.duration;
      delete l.duration
    }
    if (typeof l.complete !== "undefined") {
      s = l.complete;
      delete l.complete
    }
    if (typeof l.queue !== "undefined") {
      f = l.queue;
      delete l.queue
    }
    if (typeof l.delay !== "undefined") {
      u = l.delay;
      delete l.delay
    }
    if (typeof i === "undefined") {
      i = t.fx.speeds._default
    }
    if (typeof r === "undefined") {
      r = t.cssEase._default
    }
    i = y(i);
    var p = d(l, i, r, u);
    var h = t.transit.enabled && n.transition;
    var b = h ? parseInt(i, 10) + parseInt(u, 10) : 0;
    if (b === 0) {
      var g = function(t) {
        a.css(l);
        if (s) {
          s.apply(a)
        }
        if (t) {
          t()
        }
      };
      c(a, f, g);
      return a
    }
    var m = {};
    var v = function(e) {
      var i = false;
      var r = function() {
        if (i) {
          a.unbind(o, r)
        }
        if (b > 0) {
          a.each(function() {
            this.style[n.transition] = m[this] || null
          })
        }
        if (typeof s === "function") {
          s.apply(a)
        }
        if (typeof e === "function") {
          e()
        }
      };
      if (b > 0 && o && t.transit.useTransitionEnd) {
        i = true;
        a.bind(o, r)
      } else {
        window.setTimeout(r, b)
      }
      a.each(function() {
        if (b > 0) {
          this.style[n.transition] = p
        }
        t(this).css(l)
      })
    };
    var z = function(t) {
      this.offsetWidth;
      v(t)
    };
    c(a, f, z);
    return this
  };

  function p(e, i) {
    if (!i) {
      t.cssNumber[e] = true
    }
    t.transit.propertyMap[e] = n.transform;
    t.cssHooks[e] = {
      get: function(n) {
        var i = t(n).css("transit:transform");
        return i.get(e)
      },
      set: function(n, i) {
        var r = t(n).css("transit:transform");
        r.setFromString(e, i);
        t(n).css({
          "transit:transform": r
        })
      }
    }
  }

  function h(t) {
    return t.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(t) {
      return "-" + t.toLowerCase()
    })
  }

  function b(t, e) {
    if (typeof t === "string" && !t.match(/^[\-0-9\.]+$/)) {
      return t
    } else {
      return "" + t + e
    }
  }

  function y(e) {
    var n = e;
    if (typeof n === "string" && !n.match(/^[\-0-9\.]+/)) {
      n = t.fx.speeds[n] || t.fx.speeds._default
    }
    return b(n, "ms")
  }
  t.transit.getTransitionValue = d;
  return t
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: auto;
}

.img-container {
margin-top:100px;

margin-left: 500px;

  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

#first {
  z-index: 6;
}

#fourth {
  z-index: 5;
 left:-100px;
}

#fifth {
  z-index: 4;
 left:-100px;
}

#sixth {
  z-index: 4;
 left:-100px;
}

#second {
  z-index: 5;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button id="open">open</button>
    <button id="close">close</button>
    <div class="img-container">
      <img id="first" class="border absolute" src="http://placehold.it/100x100.jpg" alt="" />
      <div id="group">
        <img id="second" class="border absolute" src="http://placehold.it/100x100.jpg" alt="" />
        <img id="third" class="border absolute " src="http://placehold.it/100x100.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <img id="fourth" class="border absolute none" src="http://placehold.it/200x100.jpg" alt="" />
      <img id="fifth" class="border absolute none" src="http://placehold.it/200x100.jpg" alt="" />
      <img id="sixth" class="border absolute none" src="http://placehold.it/200x100.jpg" alt="" /></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="transit.js"></script>
  <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following in your code to reset to the original small square.

```
$('#close').click(function() {

    $('#fifth').css({
        display:'none'
    });

    $('#sixth').css({
        display:'none'
    });

    $('#first').removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#close').click(function() {
$('#first').removeAttr('style');
$('#second').removeAttr('style');
$('#third').removeAttr('style');
$('#group').removeAttr('style');
$('#fourth').removeAttr('style');
$('#fifth').removeAttr('style');
$('#sixth').removeAttr('style');
});
```

seems to fix the issue